# Libgdx android icon not being applied

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I made a game and now I want to change the icon, so I replaced the icons on res/drawable (with the same file name). But when I run the game on my android phone it still installs with the default libgdx icon and not my own icon. Then I tried to change the icon names and also making changes in my manifest file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/loh_icon" //loh_icon.png is my icon name
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
```

Still the same problem, how can my game still have the default libgdx icon? I deleted those icons and replaced them. I also invalidated my intellij caches and restarted.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue right now

Comment: @Flizzet I think the problem is on my phone, because I tried it on another phone and there was no problem on the icon.

Comment: That's what I did as well. I believe it's because I use a special launcher: Eve, which has icon changing capabilities. Are you using a special launcher?

Comment: yes nova launcher.

Comment: I'm assuming that's what the issue is. While testing the app, it used the default icon, and it simply saved that as the icon for the app and didn't change when updated, meaning it wouldn't happen for other users. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4):

If you look in your `android/res` folder, you'll see 5 different directories starting with `drawable`. The part after the dash is the screen density.

[image: res folder]

Inside each folder there is a file called `ic_launcher.png` with a size for each screen density. This is why by default, you'll find this in your manifest: `@drawable/ic_launcher`. You'll need to make different resolutions for different densities, and replace them.

You can use this online tool to automatically do it for you: [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html).
Make your icon and click the download link. Open the ZIP file, and extract it to your `res` folder.

[image: res folder 2]

You can delete the drawable folders. Go into your manifest, and set your icon to: `@mipmap/ic_launcher`

Comment: I don't want to use an online tool, but that is exactly what I did. Created an icon for each density and replaced the default icon then edited my manifest. But I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio just right click over android/res -> new/image asset, on dialog choose icon_laucher and the radiobox for image, there you can select whichever image you want. Android will make all different images for you

Answer (score 0):

Some phones will cache app icons. This means that it might keep showing you the old app icon even after you change it.

Try restarting the phone. Alternatively, you can try changing the theme of the phone if it has such an option (e.g: MIUI)

Answer (score 0):

Android API 26 introduced adaptive icons:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

libGDX provides new files that handle this. Use the libGDX setup wizard to generate a blank project to see it. The files are stored in:

```
android/res/drawable-apydpi-v26
```

You can edit ic_launcher_foreground.xml and ic_launcher.xml to set it up for API 26+ devices.